# python pptx unable to auto fit the text box/frame window boundary

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I have this `PPT` slide which has few text boxes. Now, through my code, I am inserting content into each of these text boxes and what I want is that the text box boundary/outline should auto fit and expand to show the entire text of that text box within the boundary. Here's my code so far:

```
def insert_text(text_frame, content_texts):
    
    # Add content texts to the text frame
    for content_text in content_texts:
        paragraph = text_frame.add_paragraph()
        paragraph.text = content_text
        paragraph.space_after = Pt(12)  

    text_frame.fit_text(font_family='Arial', max_size=12, bold=False, italic=False)
    #this one throws error as not a valid method for text_frame
    # text_frame.autofit_text()
    text_frame.word_wrap = False # I tried setting it to true as well
    text_frame.auto_size = MSO_AUTO_SIZE.SHAPE_TO_FIT_TEXT
    

def new_slide(slide_path, texts):
    
    ppt_template = Presentation(slide_path)
    #this is a sample code line
    slide = ppt_template.slides[0]

    for section_text, content_texts_array in texts.items():
        if slide is not None:
            #this is a sample code line to get text_frame
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                text_frame = shape.text_frame
            if text_frame is not None:
                # Add content texts to the same text frame and adjust text box size
                insert_text(text_frame, content_texts_array)
```

When I execute above code, I can see the text being added to the text boxes, but the window/outline of the text box doesn't resize to cover the entire text. Output looks something like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text box boundary doesn't auto adjust and remains same as it was in the PPT before the content were inserted into the text box/frame. The third sentence in the image is still inside the text box, but the bondary didn't adjusted to show it so.

How do I auto-resize the text boxes so that they cover the entire content within their boundary and also don't overlap with other text boxes either above or below them?